# Display Currency field in subject of a visualforce email template

Tags: visualforce, email-template, multi-currency

Is there a way, using the standard visualforce functions, to render a currency value in the subject of a visualforce email template?

This:

`<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Amount: {!relatedTo.Amount}">`

renders $5.00 as `5`.

This:

`<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Amount: {!relatedTo.Amount + 0.00}">`

renders $5.00 as `5.00`.

Is there an easier way to determine the currency symbol that should be displayed without doing a lookup and a large number of `IF` functions?

Comment: how can you show if user's currency is USD and record currency is EUR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable currency in your org then you can try below code:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="User" relatedToType="Opportunity" 
subject="Amount:{!relatedTo.CurrencyISOCode} {!relatedTo.Amount}"
>
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: But The commas are not coming in amount field, I need to add this in my subject line of the email.Can you please advise? I am using custom Visual force Email template